# Get last modified user of a file and creator user in Java

Tags: java, file

I know that we can get lastModified date for a file using File.lastModified() but I am not sure if there is a way i can get the username who modified the file and who created the file?

Because we have a server that everyone in the team has access. So we are planning to build a program that gives us a list of usernames who created the file and who modified the file last time.

This is on Windows OS.

Comment: You can solve your problem with Windows Audit ACLs. The modifications will show up in the Event Log (or some reporting tools). I dont think it is a good idea to code this in Java since you have only limited system access. Much faster with on-board tools. https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/acl_audit_file_folder.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 4):

You can get a whole lot of additional File attributes with the java.nio classes, especially the [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) utility class which has `Files.getOwner()` or can retrieve a [PosixFileAttributeView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributeView.html).

Note that I think most filesystems have only the notion of a owner, not a creator/last modifier.

Comment: (This is an answer to the previous version of the question, I think you should have described your problem in the first place (on SuperUser.com).