# Java watcherservice with user details who made the change

Tags: java, file-watcher

Java WatcherService doesn't gives user details which can be used to track who made the change or by whom file has been created/modified/deleted.

Explored apache commons vfs library but doesn't supports user level details.

Is there a way we can track down user details on top of WatcherService during file watcher notification?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107985/get-last-modified-user-of-a-file-and-creator-user-in-java for windows

Comment: @gargkshitiz It doesn't helps to identify the user who made the change on each file watcher event notification. It just gives out the owner of the file.

Comment: Is it windows/linux?

Comment: For both platforms in common